# Is it possible to assign initial value to a const variable after its decleration statement in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to assign initial value to a const variable after its decleration statement in javascript like below? I've tried it but didn't work. I wonder if any other ways exist.

```
const x;

x = 5;
```

Thanks.

Comment: There is no such thing as const variable. They are a constant for a reason: they do not vary.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[No](http://jsfiddle.net/juco/vGKZd/2/).

Constants must be assigned at the time of declaration and cannot be changed afterwards.

```
const x;
x = 2;
console.log(x); // == undefined

const z = 4;
z = 10;
console.log(z); // == 4
```

Answer (score 2):

> The value of a constant cannot change through re-assignment, and a constant cannot be re-declared. Because of this, although it is possible to declare a constant without initializing it, it would be useless to do so.

-- [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const)

Of course, it's quite possible on the browsers that don't support `const`, but I doubt that's what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Harmony wiki](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:const) and the [ES6 draft](https://people.mozilla.com/%7Ejorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-12.2.1) an initialiser must be present in a `const` declaration.

The wiki says:

> syntactic requirement: `const` declarations must have initializers for each declared identifier

which speaks for itself I think.

The draft doesn't state this requirement explicitly, but it can be deduced from the syntax definition (if I understand correctly. It says:

```
LexicalBinding :
    BindingIdentifier Initialiseropt
    BindingPattern Initialiser
```

and

> *LexicalBinding* : *BindingIdentifier*
>
> It is a Syntax Error if *IsConstantDeclaration* of the *LexicalDeclaration* containing this production is `true`.

As I understand, the `LexicalBinding` production rule cannot be `BindingIdentifier Initialiseropt` for a `const`, so it must be `BindingPattern Initialiser` where, as you can see, the initialiser is not marked as optional.

Answer (score 1):

## When in Doubt, Reach for the Spec!

Or in that case, as of today, the [proposed spec](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony%3aconst) for [Harmony](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony%3aharmony):

> syntactic requirement: const declarations must have initializers for each declared identifier

So `const x;` should be illegal. Though, of course, implementations vary. Some browsers may let you initialize the variable this way as `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

`const x = 5;`

but this is not widely supported, i.e. it will fail on internet explorer. Works on Google Chrome though.
I would not recommend using the `const` keyword in javascript as it is not implemented very well...